# Replace rear bearing of Dewalt DWS520 Type 1 track saw

Tags: woodworking, circular-saw

I would like to replace the rear bearing from a Dewalt DWS520 Type 1. I am not getting the armature removed. I did remove the yellow cover, but the armature is still stuck in the body of the saw. Can someone tell me how to remove the armature, so I can replace the rear bearing? Should I be able to pull him lose (tried that already, but it seems really stuck), or should I first open the gearcase on the backside and replace the gasket afterwards?

Many thanks for your answer!

Best regards, 
Peter

Comment: That nut right over there, that's the one.  https://www.dewalt.com/support/

Comment: Hi Alaska man, Thanks for your response.  Sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you mean. what nut do you mean? If I look at the Dewalt Spare image for the saw, I don't see a nut at the armature.

Comment: I was making a *sarcastic remark* to illustrate that we **can not see what you are looking at**. so let me be more clear.  **We can not see the armature or any other part of the unit you are working on**. You did not provide a link to a photo or a schematic drawing of the saw or a link to the repair manual so it is difficult to help you. I could spend an hour researching how to do it but i think **you should be doing that**. so i provided a link to Dewalt customer support.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at an [exploded view of that saw](https://servicenet.dewalt.com/Products/Detail?isId=true&productNumber=DWS520K&selectedType=18469), and there are bearings listed as replacement parts (part No's 66 and 68), which is usually the tell-tale sign that they are replaceable. That may however be difficult if you don't have the right tools and skill sets, such as a bearing puller and a press to re-install them. I would call DeWalt.